# Merge JSON objects by joining common fields

Tags: json, merge, jq

I have 2 locale file and want to group different words into same key

file1 en.json

```
{
    "name": "Apple",
    "error": {
        "payment": {
            "value1": "v1"
        }
    }
}
```

file2 zh.json

```
{
    "name": "orange",
    "error": {
        "payment": {
            "value1": "v2",
            "value2": "v5"
        }
    }
}
```

expected result

```
{
    "name": "Apple\norange",
    "error": {
        "payment": {
            "value1": "v1\nv2",
            "value2": "v5"
        }
    }
}
```

I try `jq -s . en.json zh.json | jq '.[]'| jq -s`, but it can't combine by key.

```
{
  "name": "orange",
  "error": {
    "payment": {
      "value1": "v2",
      "value2": "v5"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do your actual inputs contain fields with integer/boolean values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're trying to solve as far as I understand it is that you're taking a set of json that fits some structure and you want to collect all values set on the same json path and construct an object with the aggregated values.

For a general approach assuming there will be no arrays in this structure, you could break out all the scalar values on the set of objects (streams will be helpful with this), group them by the path, then reconstruct the object structure.

```sh
$ jq -n '
[inputs | tostream | select(length==2)] #1
  | group_by(.[0]) #2
  | map({
      path: .[0][0],
      values: [.[][1]]
    }) #3
  | reduce .[] as {$path, $values} (
      {};
      setpath($path; $values | join("\n"))
    ) #4
' en.json zh.json
```

Note the `-n` flag.

1. Converts the objects to an array of path/value pairs from a stream
2. Groups the pairs by the path
3. Maps the grouped pairs to something more readable (not necessary)
4. Creates a new object based on the groupings. Also takes the array of values and combines them as a single `\n` delimited string. (as you needed in the expected result)

https://jqplay.org/s/Aa2KoeS2M6

Answer (score 0):

The logic of the transformation you have in mind escapes me, but given the
inputs in your example, the following does produce the required result
and can easily be extended in various ways:

```
jq -n '
  input as $one
  | input as $two
  | reduce ($two | paths(scalars)) as $p  ($one;
      getpath($p) as $v
      | ($two | getpath($p)) as $x
      | if $v
        then setpath($p; "\($v)\n\($x)")
        else setpath($p; $x)
        end)
' en.json zh.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Or similarly, the same query could be achieved using `jtc` - unix *JSON* processor:

```
bash $ <en.json jtc -mi zh.json / -w'<>i:' -u'<>i:' -T'"{$a}\n{$b}"'
{
   "error": {
      "payment": {
         "value1": "v1\nv2",
         "value2": "v5"
      }
   },
   "name": "Apple\norange"
}
```

- The first chain (`-mi zh.json`) recursively merges both JSONs;
- the second chain (`-w'<>i:' -u'<>i:' -T'"{$a}\n{$b}"'`) concatenates scalars resulted from the merge

PS. it so happens, that i'm also the creator of the `jtc`.
PPS. the above disclaimer is required by SO.